# Encode JSON string before deserialize

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0, json.net

I am getting raw JSON format as a string(without encoded) from third party.  So I am getting parse error message when I try to deserialize string because of extra double quotes. Is it possible to serialize string before deserialization on my end or escape any special characters before deserialization? Please let me know. 
I tried to do replace with backslash but it didn't work.

```
{
  "Detail":{
     "date1": "06-JAN-2016",
     "summary": "test """""""""""",
     "city": "TEST"
     }
}

string escapeJson = jsonFile.Replace(@"\", "");


var myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(escapeJson);


public class RootObject
{
    public Detail detail { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public DateTime date1{ get; set; }
    public string summary{ get; set; }
    public string city{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That means the JSON is not valid. This issue needs to be fixed on the serialization side or the producing side, NOT the deserialization (consuming side)

Comment: is it possible to correct on my end because I have no control of producing side?

Comment: There is a reason why strings *must* be escaped before serialization. You are facing that one reason.

Comment: CodingYoshi is right, the json data coming is not valid and therefore cannot be parsed by Json. Contact the api endpoint owner to fix the issue from their side so that you may receive valid json.